# CGContextRef vs NSGraphicsContext

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I just started learning OSX programming, and I've stumbled upon a problem where I don't know if I should use `CGContextRef` or `NSGraphicsContext`.

What is the difference?

I barely know the difference between CG or NS [and how they relate to cocoa] (I've tried googling to no avail)

Could anybody shed some light on when I would want to use either, or what the key differences are?

I'd take a link to an article, even.  I just can't find anything from my web searches.

I know I'm asking a lot of questions in one, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who's reading this, 
NSGraphicsContext layers on top of CGContextRef; and similar to most CG<->NS relations, the NS counterpart mirrors the CG's basic functionality.

But NSGraphicsContext allows you to do a little more, such as 'graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort' to create context from a graphics port.

Comment: at least, that's all I could tell

Answer (score 0):

CG based commands use a C like syntax.  NS based commands use the Objective-c style interface;

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)nr
{

    NSGraphicsContext* gc = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef cggc = [gc CGContext];

    CGPathRef cgp = CGPathCreateMutable();
// do CGPath stuff
    CGContextFlush(cggc);


    NSBezierPath* nzb = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];

// Do NSPath stuff

    [gc flushGraphics];

}
```